# jQuery Cycle with Cufon Pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, cufon, jquery-cycle

So, I am using jQuery with Cufon and jQuery Cycle. What I want, is the pager of Cycle to have Cufon fonts.

Below is my JS

```
var pagerclass;

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#slider").cycle({
        fx: "scrollHorz",
        timeout: 7000,
        pager: "#pager ul",
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            if(idx==0) pagerclass = "first"; else if(idx==2) pagerclass="last"; else pagerclass="";
            Cufon.replace("#pager ul");
            return "<li class='"+pagerclass+"'><a href='#'>"+slide.title+"</a></li>";
        }
    });

});
```

So the `Cufon.replace("#pager ul");`-line is not working, because it doesn't replace the last item. The last item gets returned after that.

Is there any way to do something in jQuery Cycle after the Pager is built? That would solve the problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    function cufrep() {

        Cufon('#pager ul');

    }


    $("#slider").cycle({
        fx: "scrollHorz",
        timeout: 7000,
        pager: "#pager ul",
        after: cufrep, // after
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
            if(idx==0) pagerclass = "first"; else if(idx==2) pagerclass="last"; else pagerclass="";
            Cufon.replace("#pager ul");
            return "<li class='"+pagerclass+"'><a href='#'>"+slide.title+"</a></li>";
        }
    });

});
```

Cufon has an after function which fires *after*.

Comment: The after-function is "transition callback" according to the Options Reference, so for _after_ transition to different slide. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html